# Is it necessary to re-analyze an elasticsearch copy_to if the original content has been analyzed?

Tags: elasticsearch

We have an elasticsearch mapping using a copy_to (custom _all). It is only used for queries and is not stored. We analyze the original file_content_de using "analyzer": "german". Do we also need to analyze the copy_to, the ES documentation is not really clear about this?

**ES documentation:** https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/custom-all.html

```
    "attachment_contents_de": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    ...
    "file_content_de": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "german",
        "copy_to":  "attachment_contents_de",
        "include_in_all": false, 
        "store":true
    },
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you have to analyze the copied field seperately as the official documentations mentions.

and this doesn't mean re-analyze, the copy_to copies the string values to the field, where the field in itself should have its own definition along with analyzers defined

```
Mappings of the first_name and last_name fields have no bearing on how the full_name field is indexed. The full_name field copies the string values from the other two fields, then indexes them according to the mapping of the full_name field only.
```

You can define mappings for the `attachment_contents_de` with your suitable analyzer.

Thanks